# jQuery: check if the CSS of a div: left == 0

Tags: jquery, css, class

I have want to change a every div that has **left=0**.

I try to let jQuery check. This is how I did it:

```
if ($('.box').css("left") == "0"){
        $('.box').addClass("active");
    }
```

It isn't working for me. Does anyone have a solution?

```js
if ($('.fiets').css("left") == "0") {
  $('.fiets').addClass("active");
}
```

```css
.box {
  width: 20vw;
  height: 20vw;
  background: #6989FF;
  position: absolute;
  border: solid 1px red;
  transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
  <article class="box"></article>
  <article class="box"></article>
  <article class="box"></article>
  <article class="box"></article>
  <article class="box"></article>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you add some HTML? possibly as a snippet?

Comment: Your html doe not contain a div with the class `fiets` therefore the element can not be found.

Comment: Changed it to box, forgot i changed it hahah, but it still isn't working! :P

Comment: Hope it's a folding bike then (sorry couldn't resist this bad joke)

Comment: Also change the '==' to '==='

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) can operate on collections, it can only do so while setting properties, not when reading their values. If you try to do that, it'll just return the value for the first element in your collection. You have to iterate each element.

Also, as [@Stefan noted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52988601#answer-52988710), the computed value includes `px` units.

```
$('.box').each(function() {
  if ($(this).css("left") == "0px") {
    $(this).addClass("active");
  }
})
```

Comment: Hey, i got a question tho, i have more divs, now if they move and a other div gets left:0, and the one with the class "active" goes to let say left=20vw, it keeps the class "active" and the div that goes to left=0, doesnt get the class "active". How do i do this?

Comment: @rutgervs That executes on `document.ready` only, that's why it doesn't respond to changes. Furthermore, a `div` element doesn't fire a `change` event, only `inputs` do, so you'd need to use [MutationObservers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) or React or something like that. You can find several questions about it in here.

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the unit of the "left" css attribute (i.e. "0px")

Answer (score 1):

1. set `px` `== "0px"`
2. add `left:0;` in css

```js
if ($('.box').css("left") == "0px"){
        $('.box').addClass("active");
    }
```

```css
.box {
 width: 20vw;
 height: 20vw;
  left:0;
 background: #6989FF;
 position: absolute;
 border: solid 1px red;
 transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}
.active{
background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="slider">
   <article class="box"></article>
   <article class="box"></article>
   <article class="box"></article>
   <article class="box"></article>
   <article class="box"></article>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Code like this.It will work.

1.add left=0 in css

```
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"> </script>
<style>
div.active
{
color:red;
}
</style>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$("button").click(function(){
div_left_value=document.getElementById("box").style.left;
    if(div_left_value== '0px'){
$('.box').addClass("active");}
});
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<div style="height:100px;width:300px;padding:10px;margin:3px;border:1px solid 
blue;background-color:lightblue;left:0" class="box" id="box">ff</div><br>

<button>Display the width of div</button>

</body>
</html>
```